# Use filter on field name with single underscore

Tags: django, django-views, django-models, django-filter

I have a field with the name `end_date`, and when I try to use filter in my view:

```
c = Coursera.objects.filter(end_date__lt = datetime.date.today()).order_by('-date')[:1].get()
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'date' into field. Choices are:...

`end_` is being completely ignored; hence, I would assume that `end` is possibly a keyword; clearly, I can change the field name to something else; however, my question is: is there another way to still use that field name and be able to use the filter?

P.S. I thought keywords such as `lt`, or `gt` are only used after *two underscores*!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think `end_` is a keyword, error is probably because of `order_by('-date')`. Seems like you do not have a field `date` in your model but you are trying to fetch the result order by date field.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
if not re.match(r'^[_]+$', username):
    raise forms.ValidationError("Sorry , you can only have  _  in username")
```